# How to create 2 actions with same path but different http methods Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, http-method

I work with symfony routing annotation and I have already set the `http_method_override` to `true`

I want to create two different actions but with a different behaviour according to the http method like this:

```
/**
 * Event controller.
 *
 * @Route("/event")
 */
class EventController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Event entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="event")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template() // default template (index.html.twig)
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
       ...
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Event entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="event_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("...") // a special template new.html.twig
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }
```

But when I try to access to /event/, there is a 405 page saying :

> No route found for "GET /event/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

And when I try to list my routes with `php app/console router:debug` :

```
  event_create             POST   ANY    ANY  /event/                                      
  event                    GET    ANY    ANY  /event/week/{timestamp}                      
  event_new                GET    ANY    ANY  /event/new
  event_show               GET    ANY    ANY  /event/{id}                                  
  event_edit               GET    ANY    ANY  /event/{id}/edit
  event_update             PUT    ANY    ANY  /event/{id}
  event_delete             DELETE ANY    ANY  /event/{id}
```

Comment: You can also create only one route and add the 2 methods togheter like this `@Method({"GET", "POST"})`

Comment: Thx for your quick answer gp_sflover but I need to get two different behaviours (list and create), so two different methods. But I've found my stupid answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I've just realized reading my question that **an other method below** with the path /event/week/{timestamp} **was named "event" too** :/

So I renamed this method to event_week and it works.

Comment: unbelievable i had the same issue! With the same solution... It's a more common problem than i tought